# How do I add mnemonics to java.awt.Menu?

Tags: java, menu, awt, mnemonics

How do I add mnemonics (i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + something) to `java.awt.Menu` (not `javax.swing.JMenu`)?

For a `JMenu` it's simple:

```java
mnFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

But I cannot find relevant information about `Menu`. Do I have to use low level mechanics (i.e. `KeyListener`) to accomplish this?

I'm using Windows 10 and Java 8.